# Does Chibiusa have the Imperium Silver Crystal?

Tags: sailor-moon

In *Sailor Moon S*, Chibiusa says she came back to the twentieth century to train with the sailor scouts. Her first shown transformation (where she uses Moon Prism Power Makeup) is seen in episode 104.

Does she use the Silver Crystal first shown in *Sailor Moon R* (shown during the fight against the Death Phantom (a.k.a. Wiseman)) to transform into Chibi Moon?